# Orderby property not working properly in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I have a table consists of 3 columns like below,

Column A || Column B|| Column C

20    ||     Raj   ||   Driver

50    ||    John   ||  Driver

30    ||  Bharath ||  Driver

40    ||    Jack    ||  Driver

I have wriiten orderBy property to sort.
If I sort by column A, both Column B and Column C will sort according to A(Correct).
But if i sort by Column C, both Column A and Column B are sorting according to C... But it should not sort because column C have same values. 
Is there any filter property to achieve this? If same value in column is present then it all the columns should not sort? Is it Possible?

Code:

```
<div ng-controller="ExampleController">
 <pre>Sort by = {{propertyName}}; reverse = {{reverse}}</pre>
  <hr/>
  <button ng-click="propertyName = null; reverse = false">Set to unsorted</button>
  <hr/>
  <table class="friends">
    <tr>
      <th>
        <button ng-click="sortBy('num')">Column A</button>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'num'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button ng-click="sortBy('name')">Column B</button>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'name'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
      </th>
      <th>
        <button ng-click="sortBy('occupation')">Column C</button>
        <span class="sortorder" ng-show="propertyName === 'occupation'" ng-class="{reverse: reverse}"></span>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | orderBy:propertyName:reverse">
      <td>{{friend.num}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.name}}</td>
      <td>{{friend.occupation}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: please share code.

Comment: I have added code